# Can kineticits use Foe Throw and Many Throw infusion t the same time fore crowd control offense?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, kineticist

Can kineticits use [Foe Throw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/infusion-wild-talents/#Foe_Throw) and [Many Throw](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/kineticist/infusion-wild-talents/#Many_Throw) infusion at the same time for crowd control offense?

By picking up creatures equal to their level and Fort save per critter picked up and fling them to a wall or other creature and deal damage to each other? Also if metakinetic feat as Empower Spell is used, is the x1.5 damage applied to all the affected targets [the creatures tossed and the target tossed on]?

Answer (score 3):

### No, these infusions can't be combined because they are both *form* infusions

As the Kineticist's [Infusion](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Kineticist/#Infusion_Su) ability describes:

> Each time the kineticist uses one of her kinetic blast wild talents, she can apply up to one associated form infusion and up to one associated substance infusion.

Foe Throw and Many Throw are both *form infusions*, so you cannot use them both on a single kinetic blast - you must choose at most one of them to use for any given blast.

However, if you want to be able to throw a lot of foes in one turn, you *can* use the Kineticist's [Metakinesis](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Kineticist/#Metakinesis_Su) - the 13th level option can quicken the kinetic blast to use it as a swift action, and the 17th level option allows you to produce two blasts with a single action. Combined, those would allow you to use a swift double blast and a standard action double blast to target up four different creatures and throw them at up to four more creatures, albeit you would have to have [gathered power](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Kineticist/#Gather_Power_Su) on the turn prior and make use of your [Internal Buffer](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/occult-adventures/occult-classes/Kineticist/#Internal_Buffer_Su) in order to able to get through that much burn in a single round.

Comment: Then would Foe Throw infusion with Dual Telekinetic Control utility work together to throw 2 creatures at another creature or target?

Comment: @JhyarelleSilver you mean the 17th level double blast metakinesis? Yes, that would allow you to throw two different enemies. By my reading you could throw the two affected creatures at different targets if you like. The cost is a lot of burn, of course.

Comment: No not that, I plan doing this early as like level 6-7. Foe Throw infusion let you toss a creature as an infusion to simple TK Blast. Dual TK Control is a utility that lets you use simple TK Blast using two separate things and throwing them at a target. [http://spheresofpower.wikidot.com/aether-utility-talents#toc11] Is this combination acceptable to do crowd control by tossing two creatures at another.